# "Lockdown will be lifted" vs "Block will be removed" vs "blockade will be lifted"

Tags: word-choice

If a website is blocked, and I wish for it to be unblocked, which of the following is the best way to put it?

- *"The blockade will be lifted tomorrow"*
- *"The block will be removed tomorrow"*
- *"Lockdown will be lifted tomorrow"*

Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Blockade* generally refers to a physical obstacle that prevents things from passing freely. *Lockdown* usually refers to policies with widespread blanket restrictions, which might be more appropriate for restricting access to the internet entirely, rather than blocking a few sites. In the age of active shooters and COVID, "lockdown" has connotations that would likely be undesired.

The best option is to refer to it as a a *block*, or refer to the blocking software itself as a *blocker*. You can use either "remove" or "lift" to describe an easing of the restrictions.

> The block will be removed/lifted tomorrow.

Comment: Or simply "Unblock it tomorrow".